# Compare C char arrays of varying lengths

Tags: c, arrays, function, compare

I want to greate a function that will determine if a C character array(not string, no null terminator) is less than another. For my uses, if one array ends and another doesn't you keep testing the last character against the other array ends. Capitals don't matter so I'm trying to use tolower()

Examples.
Aaah should be less than America
Watermelon should be less than wade
Watermelon should NOT be less than water.
Hello should be less than HelloWorld

How can I write a function to do this, given the size of both arrays?

Comment: How do you konw you reach the end of the array if it's not null terminated ?

Comment: do you want to compare arbitrary data or strings?

Comment: _Watermelon should be less than wade_?

Comment: What if one array has size zero, i. e. there is no _last character_?

Answer (score 0):

Go through both arrays starting at index 0 and compare the characters at each index.  If the characters are the same, go to the next index, and once they're not the same then you'll know which array is less than the other.